# command not found but found when i drag and drop

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, terminal, kali-linux

i run flutter command in the flutter directory but it says command not found

```
root/korra:/Desktop/flutter/bin# flutter  
bash: flutter: command not found
```

but if i drag and drop the flutter to terminal whole path will comes under single quotes and run everything

```
root@Korra:~# '/root/Desktop/flutter/bin/flutter' 
   Woah! You appear to be trying to run flutter as root.
   We strongly recommend running the flutter tool without superuser privileges.
  /

Manage your Flutter app development.

Common commands:

  flutter create <output directory>
    Create a new Flutter project in the specified directory.

  flutter run [options]
    Run your Flutter application on an attached device or in an emulator.


Run "flutter help <command>" for more information about a command.
Run "flutter help -v" for verbose help output, including less commonly used
options.
```

this is happening to other files also

Answer (score 0):

You need to prefix the command with `./` to run commands in the current directory, so: `./flutter`.